# How can I run a quiz or survey on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I want to test the suitability of a web-page control. Can I post a multiple-choice survey in an appropriate group? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How can I run a quiz or survey on SO?

The short and long of it is you can't. SO imposes very strict limitations on what can and can't be posted in order to keep a strong focus on programming Q&A, and high quality.

Answer (score 11):

This is probably covered with the "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" section of [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), emphasis mine:

> #### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - **every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”**
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use `______` for `______`, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if `______` happened?”
>     it is a rant disguised as a question: “`______` sucks, am I right?”

If you don't feel that is the case, then you may give it a shot, but I would predict it wouldn't last long.